# Проверить наличие записи в таблице и вернуть true или false

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица пользователей:

```
 user_id |  user_name  | ... |
------------------------------
   1     |    name 1   | ... |
   2     |    name 2   | ... |
   3     |    name 3   | ... |
```

Какой должен быть запрос, чтобы проверить, есть ли пользователь с `user_id` в таблице пользователей, если есть - вернуть `true`, а если нет - вернуть `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов много, но вот простой:

```
select count(*) <> 0 from users where user_id = id;
```

Если есть значение, то будет одна строка, если нет, то 0. Неравенство приведет какраз к True\False.

Comment: Это понятно. Если  мне понятдобится из таблице продуктов запросить, то есть, вывести весь список продуктов, и указать если в закладках у пользователя продук, если есть вернуть `true` и если нет векрнуть`false`?

Comment: @MegaRoks дополните вопрос недостоющей информацией

Comment: или задайте новый вопрос. там через join делается. надо видеть как устроенны таблицы закладок и продуктов

Comment: @MegaRoks здесь нужен новый вопрос, потому, что Вы получили абсолютно исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос, который задали